# LocalDate in java to be persisted with JPA as date in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a Policy class as below

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "Policy")
public class Policy {

```
private Long policyId;
private Long customerId;
private Long vehicleId;

@Convert(converter =LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
private LocalDate policyStartDate;

@Convert(converter =LocalDateAttributeConverter.class)
private LocalDate policyEndDate;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "POLICYID_GEN", sequenceName = "policyId_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "POLICYID_GEN")
@Column(name = "PolicyId")
public Long getPolicyId() {
    return policyId;
}

public void setPolicyId(Long policyId) {
    this.policyId = policyId;
}

@Column(name = "CustomerId")
public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

@Column(name = "VehicleId")
public Long getVehicleId() {
    return vehicleId;
}

public void setVehicleId(Long vehicleId) {
    this.vehicleId = vehicleId;
}

@Column(name = "PolicyStartDate")
public LocalDate getPolicyStartDate() {
    return policyStartDate;
}

public void setPolicyStartDate(LocalDate policyStartDate) {
    this.policyStartDate = policyStartDate;
}

@Column(name = "PolicyEndDate")
public LocalDate getPolicyEndDate() {
    return policyEndDate;
}

public void setPolicyEndDate(LocalDate policyEndDate) {
    this.policyEndDate = policyEndDate;
}
```

I am trying to persist the same using JPA but getting below error

> Hibernate: select policyId_seq.nextval from dual Policy
>   [policyId=1006, customerId=1, vehicleId=1, policyStartDate=2019-01-01,
>   policyEndDate=2019-12-31] Hibernate: insert into Policy (CustomerId,
>   PolicyEndDate, PolicyStartDate, VehicleId, PolicyId) values (?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?) Dec 27, 2018 2:25:25 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet [PolicyController] in context with path
>   [/InsurancePortal] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
>   ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY ; SQL
>   [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00932: inconsistent
>   datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY ] with root cause
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes:
>   expected NUMBER got BINARY

Comment: Annotate the fields, or annotate the getters. But don't mix the two strategies.

Comment: Thanks.. Had done the same earlier but tries this way to check if converter needs to be applied at field level

Comment: @RiteshShah how did you resolve this problem? I get it when trying to persist a null into the LocalDate column